# Have comments append to a history section?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a part of a form that needs to be approved/rejected.  There is a chain of approvers so once the approver approves or rejects they submit comments explaining why, and it moves on to the next approver.  How can I make it so that the comments are appended if the approver rejects, so that when the form goes back to the person filling it out the other approvers can see why the form was rejected in the past.

Answer (score 1):

So are you using the Out of the Box forms for SHarePoint lists or INfoPath?  If you are simply using a default sharePoint list I would create a column based off the multi line text field and select append changes to text.  THis means that a flow of the comments entered would be appended acordingly. This column would be where the information is captured.

Comment: +1. To add: there is OOTB, ready-to-use 'Append-Only Comments' site column.

Comment: I am using InfoPath to create my forms.  I tagged it in my original question, but I should have specified.